# Invalid CSRF token as a result of session cookie not being set when visiting login form directly

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, twig, csrf

Updating this post following further investigation to ensure it is focussed on the actual issue (also now raised at: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42691)

#### My Environment

I am running:

- Symfony 5.3.6
- PHP version 7.3
- Debian 10 running on WSL2
- Symfony development server on localhost, accessed via Chrome on the same machine

#### Description & What I'm Trying to Achieve

- I am trying to implement a secure login form by following the Symfony tutorial (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).
- I get the error message "Invalid CSRF token." on the first login attempt but not subsequent login attempts.
- Following debugging (using Xdebug 3) it appears Symfony is not creating a session to link a CSRF token to.

#### Steps to Reproduce

- Created a new Symfony project using `symfony new test_project`
- Installed the maker bundle using `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`
- Followed the security set-up guide (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) sections 1-2
- Generated a login form using `make:auth` command following this guide https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
- Accessed https://localhost:8000/login
- Submit the login form with a valid username and password pair, along with the hidden pre-generated CSRF token

#### The Outcome I Was Expecting

- A registered user being able to login at https://localhost:8000/login

#### The Actual Outcome

- When accessing https://localhost:8000/login, no cookie is set
- When submitting the login form including the CSRF token, as there is no cookie with this request, Symfony finds no session, and so naturally finds no CSRF token
- As there is no CSRF token Symfony throwns an exception "Invalid CSRF token.". The response headers of this include a cookie that represents a session (assuming automatically, as I have followed the Symfony tutorial)
- When submitting the login form for the second time, as there is a cookie sent in the request headers, Symfony "finds" the CSRF token on the session and so the login works as expected

Comment: I usually have this problem when the form loads from cache. For example, logging out opens the login page again in my app and if the user just leaves that page open until they want to login the next time it will fail. Do you have any cache rules either in your response header or in your .htaccess?

Comment: Hi @fun2life thanks for your tip. I don't believe I have any cache rules in my response header, I haven't added any, but how would I check this? Regarding .htaccess files I found the following files:
`/home/lushawn/.cache/composer/.htaccess` `/home/lushawn/.config/composer/.htaccess`                                                                              `/home/lushawn/.local/share/composer/.htaccess`
All of which have "Deny from all" written in them. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Could you try to change your register.html.twig form to only "{{ form_start(registrationForm) }} {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}" and see if it works with the automatic rendering. Also try adding a SubmitType to the registration form instead of adding manually a submit button.

Comment: Not directly on topic but out of the box Symfony uses PHP's native session handler which on my linux system points to /var/lib/php/sessions.  The docs show how to point it to var/cache if you want.  Clearing it out might help though probably not.  Looks like you used the make:auth and make:registration-form commands which seem to work for me.  I assume you are using the Symfony development server?

Comment: Hello @alexcm thanks for your suggestion. I just tried this on the reg form and I get more strange behaviour. On initial registration attempt I get the following error:
`Key "errors" for array with keys "value, attr, form, id, name, full_name, disabled, label, label_format, label_html, multipart, block_prefixes, unique_block_prefix, row_attr, translation_domain, label_translation_parameters, attr_translation_parameters, priority, cache_key, clicked" does not exist.`

Then if I go back or navigate through links to the reg form and reattempt to register, it works... This is also repeatable

Comment: Try commenting this for now {%for error in child.vars.errors%}<li>{{error.message}}</li>{%endfor%} until you now for sure everything arrives to the view properly.

Comment: Interesting @Cerad , I am using the Symfony dev server yes. I also tried giving my caches a clear but no luck... I wonder, in my /var directory only contains a cache and a log subdirectory, does it seem like anythings missing?

Comment: This is all just guessing here but you might want to explicitly set your [session's save_path](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#configuration) just to clear up one mystery.

Comment: Well, one way to check for caching problems would be to replace the hidden token field with a text field. After logging out (I guess you‘ll be redirected to the login page, otherwise just open the login page and follow this) remember the value, close your browser window and then open the page again and check the value. And your .htaccess in question would sit in your public folder next to index.php if there is one

Comment: Thanks for thank link @Cerad it was interesting, I tried changing some of the settings as well as setting up a path to save sessions to but no luck unfortunately. I think I may have to try completely redo my authentication and login/registration controllers etc. and see if that fixes it, I am using the guard authenticator (which I know is now deprecated) but I tried changing to the new Authenticator-based Security but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: Also @fun2life I tried checking this, the token seems to change on every attempt and every reload of the page, even after closing the tab.

Comment: Would you guys mind upvoting the post in hope that it gets more attention? Many thanks :)

Comment: Upvoting is not going to get more attention.  Your starting over plan is a good idea.  Fresh project, make:user, make:auth and make:registration-form.  Except for a slight tweak to the Authenicator everything should just work as is.  If not then check the project into github and post a question on the [Symfony Discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/categories/q-a) board.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the advice, I've followed it and updated the question and also created an issue on Symfony's github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting on Symfony's github, their response helped me uncover the issue. [Here is my post for interest](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42691).

It appears the issue was that I was using **PHP 7.3** which has reached its end of life. I managed to keep all my original configuration settings in security.yaml and framework.yaml the same and get my own Symfony project to now work. However, there was nothing in Symfony that alerted me that PHP 7.3 would be incompatible.

#### What I did

- Upgraded to PHP 8.0.10 following [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-php-on-debian/)

#### The outcome

- I no longer get the CSRF error and my login functionality all works as expected on my own Symfony project.